# How can I lower the resolution on Windows 7 boot & login screen?

Tags: virtualbox, resolution, login-screen, seamless

This may be an odd question to ask because usually it's the other way around.

The reason to why I want to do this is because I want to use Windows 7 on Virtual Box in seamless mode, and I don't need nor want the window to be as large as my screen before I log in.

Post-login has to maintain it's current resolution, otherwise it won't look so seamless anymore XP

Comment: interesting question, but i don't do 7 in vbox

Comment: Can you even start seamless mode before the desktop is displayed?  I thought the virtual OS had to be at least fully loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I half found the solution to my problem. I was able to change the resolution of my login screen, but not the boot screen.

In order to change the login screen you have to open regedit and go to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{C2A9EF37-354B-4FBD-B1DE-52925094A8CA}\0000
```

and change the `XResolution` to `800` and the `YResolution` to `600`. Make sure that "decimal" is selected as the base.

**Note:** The registry will automatically change back once you log back in, maybe if I set up a script to change the registry on shutdown, it will work.

Comment: Good solution, especially the idea to change the resolution on shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of VirtualBox that I have (3.2.12) I cannot enter seamless mode at all until the desktop loads, and then I get a message that I am about to be switched to seamless mode:
[image]

Disclaimer:  I am running VirtualBox on a Mac, not under Linux.  Ymmv.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I cannot access seamless mode until the desktop loads. The reason why want to do this is because I don't want a huge window taking up my whole screen before I log in. I just want an easy manageable, and low resolution screen so this doesn't get in the way.